# xml parse multiple words in single node?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have a xml like that:

```
<item>
<name>chuck - norris</name>
</item>
```

I can get full name from there and add it to listbox with this:

```
.......
.......

public class helperclass
{
  string helper;
  public string Helper
  {
       get {return helper; }
       set {helper = value; }
  }
}

.......
.......

//xml comes from internet

void something_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
XElement xml = XElement.Parse(e.Result);   

var info = from somexml in xml.Descendants("item")
     select new helperclass
     {
        Helper = (string)somexml.Element("name")
     };

listBox1.ItemsSource = info;

.......
```

But how can I replace that " - " with line break so I can get:

chuck

norris

instead of:

chuck - norris

and how to get only first name?

Comment: Did you try using Split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Linq to XML instead:

```
         var listOfStringsYouWant = new List<string>();
         var doc = XDocument.Load("placeXMLHere");
         // finds every node of item
         doc.Descendants("item").ToList()
            .ForEach(item =>
                        {
                           listOfStringsYouWant.Add(item.Element("name").Value.Replace('-', '\r\n'));
                        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any checking:

```
string[] segments = "Chuck - Norris".Split('-');
string firstName = segments[0].Trim();
string lastName = segments[1].Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.

```
String sArray = Helper.Split('-');
foreach (String str in sArray)
Console.Writeline(Str+"\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your line break is for a text box you need to .replace it from " - " to "\r\n".

If it's for an HTML element, .replace " - " with "<br />"

And if you need to break them up so you know one from the other, use .split

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
namespace XMLParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement items = XElement.Load(@"C:\XMLParser\items.xml");

            var filteredItems = from item in items.Descendants("item")
                                select item.Element("name");

            foreach (var item in filteredItems)
            {
                // Replacing " - " with NewLine
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value.Replace(" - ",
                                                     System.Environment.NewLine));

                // Only First name
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value.Split().First());
            }
        }
    }
}
```